# Nuxt: css of error.vue appears in page rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt.

I have a page

*pages/page1.vue*

```html
<template>
   <h1 class="title">Page</h1>
</template>
<style>
  .title {
     font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Then, under layouts I have an error.vue

*layouts/error.vue*

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="title">Error Page</h1>
</template>
<style>
  .title {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
</style>
```

What I found is that when `page1` is rendered, the title appears in Red. I checked the inspect elements and found that the CSS of error as well as of page 1 is applied.

I do not have a default.vue in the layouts directory.

As mentioned this is my first project in Nuxt (or vue) and want to understand how to ensure that CSS of a page are applied on that page only. This is in development mode (npm run dev). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is CSS without scoped attribute renders at application level. You should use scoped attribute in styles tag as

*layouts/error.vue*

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="title">Error Page</h1>
</template>
<style scoped>
  .title {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
</style>
```

**When a `<style>` tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only otherwise consider global style.

Comment: Oops. This is indeed embarrasing. The auto suggest even puts it and I removed it. :-). Thanks